# How could I print the t of Bezier curve in csv file?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, bezier

This is `Bezier curve Python code` and I have printed the coordinates `X` and `Y` of the `Bezier cruve`. It means the points on the curve as a table is shown below, but I could not print `t`. Any assistance please?

```
X    Y     t
==============
```

How could I print t?.

The code below:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
def calc_bezier_path(control_points, n_points=100):
    """
    Compute bezier path (trajectory) given control points.
    :param control_points: (numpy array)
    :param n_points: (int) number of points in the trajectory
    :return: (numpy array)
    """
    traj = []
    for t in np.linspace(0, 1, n_points):
        traj.append(bezier(t, control_points))

    return np.array(traj)


def bernstein_poly(n, i, t):
    """
    Bernstein polynom.
    :param n: (int) polynom degree
    :param i: (int)
    :param t: (float)
    :return: (float)
    """
    return scipy.special.comb(n, i) * t ** i * (1 - t) ** (n - i)


def bezier(t, control_points):
    """
    Return one point on the bezier curve.
    :param t: (float) number in [0, 1]
    :param control_points: (numpy array)
    :return: (numpy array) Coordinates of the point
    """
    n = len(control_points) - 1
    return np.sum([bernstein_poly(n, i, t) * control_points[i] for i in range(n + 1)], axis=0)


visx, visy = [1,2,10,15,20,25,21], [0,5,1,4,2,3,3]
vis = np.column_stack((visx,visy))
print(vis[0])
path_x, path_y = np.array([]),np.array([])
if len(vis) > 2:
    current_control = vis[0]
    for x in range(len(vis)-2):
        if x != (len(vis)-3):
            mid_control = [(vis[x+1,0]+vis[x+2,0])/2, (vis[x+1,1]+vis[x+2,1])/2]
            plt.annotate(f"M{x}", mid_control)
            bezier_line = calc_bezier_path(np.array([current_control,vis[x+1], mid_control]))
            path_x = np.append(path_x, bezier_line.T[0])
            path_y = np.append(path_y, bezier_line.T[1])
            current_control = mid_control
        else:
            bezier_line = calc_bezier_path(np.array([current_control, vis[x+1], vis[x+2]]))
            path_x = np.append(path_x, bezier_line.T[0])
            path_y = np.append(path_y, bezier_line.T[1])
else:
    path_x, path_y = visx, visy
with open('my_csv.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    fieldnames = ['visx','visy','t']
    thewriter = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=fieldnames)
    thewriter.writeheader()
    for jjj in range(len(path_x)):
        thewriter.writerow({'visx':path_x[jjj],'visy':path_y[jjj]})
plt.plot(path_x, path_y)
plt.plot(visx, visy, "--o")
for xy in range(len(vis)):
    plt.annotate(f"P{xy}", vis[xy])
plt.show()
```

Comment: what do you mean by x, y, t ? are they points on the curve?

Comment: @DrBwts Yes dear

Comment: `x` is stored in `path_x` and `y` is stored in `path_y` not sure about `t`. If you're unsure about how to write out text file in Python have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html)

Comment: This is an incedible amount of code if all you want is to print a t/x/y table for a bezier curve. Why all the numpy/scipy code? `for i in range(0,100): t = i/100` and then just print `f"{t}\t{x}\t{y}"`, with `t` being itself, `x` as `compute(t, xcoords)` and `y` as `compute(t, ycoords)` where `compute` is your basic bezier computing function.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This is not my code dear. I have taken this code and I put some lines from me on it.

Comment: @Haitham Then [say that in your post](/help/how-to-ask). If you didn't write this code, that's information you should tell people.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have said that in the beginning of the post: I said this is ... I didn't say this is my....

Comment: That is too subtle a distinction, given that many folks posting here don't have English as their first language, and it's more than likely that when someone says "I have this code" or something similar, what they mean is they wrote it. So, please read through ["how to ask a good quesiton"](/help/how-to-ask) and update your post a bit to make things that are implied, or maybe just subtle, entirely explicit. It's a policy article we all have to follow, for the benefit of everyone - both readers, _and_ posters.